# Iterate through an object and find value by key in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects, like this

[image]

I would like to iterate through an array and find users by specific roomCode

I tried this:

```
      for(let i=0; i <data.liveRooms.length; i++) {
        if(data.liveRooms[i].roomCode === code) {
          this.usersLive = data.liveRooms[i].users;
        }
      }
```

And also this:

```
for(let i=0; i <data.liveRooms.length; i++) {
    this.liveDataDictionary[data.liveRooms[i].roomCode] = 
      data.liveRooms[i].users;
 }
  this.usersLive = this.liveDataDictionary[code];
```

But nothing works and I don't know why...could you please help me?

Comment: the first attempt you mentioned should work. try debugging it. Have you checked what this `console.log(data.liveRooms[i].roomCode)` gives you inside the for loop?

Comment: @Paritosh yes, it gives me undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the screenshot you posted, `data.liveRooms[i]` is a string, not an object.  You could try this inside your `for` loop:

```
for(let i=0; i <data.liveRooms.length; i++) {
  let liveRoom = JSON.parse(data.liveRooms[i]);
    if(liveRoom.roomCode === code) {
      ....
    }
}
```

The `JSON.parse()` method is a built-in that will convert that string that looks like an object to an actual object.  At that point you will be able to get to the dot properties of the object, like `.roomCode`.

[JSON.parse() at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Awesome.  Glad to hear it!